# How do I subtract dates from tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

How do I subtract dates from tableau?

For example, I want to subtract 1 year from a date variable.

It's from the query, not the filter.

help me

Answer (score 2):

DATEADD('year',-1,[your_field_here])

that's the best way to do it.